# Prime Factorization and Sum of Divisors not working?

Tags: javascript, math

So I restarted Project Euler when I lost all my code for it. I'm at [problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23). I know how to do it and I've done it before but it's not working right now and I've been trying to tackle it for so long, I can barely think straight. I'm using NodeJS this time around.

According to [this really simplified article](http://www.math-magic.com/misc/pos_int_div2.htm), I can use the prime factorization to figure out the sum of a number's divisors. So I have these two functions:

```
Util.GetPrimeFactors = function (val) {
    var init = val;
    var num = 2;
    var primes = {};
    while (val > 1) {
        if (val % num == 0) {
            if (num == init) return [];// prevent prime numbers from including themselves
            if (primes[num]) {
                primes[num]++;
            } else {
                primes[num] = 1;
            }
            val /= num;
        } else {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

Util.SumOfDivisors = function (val) {
    var primes = Util.GetPrimeFactors(val);
    var coeff = primes[0];
    var count = 0;
    var total = 1;
    for (var i in primes) {
        count++;
        if (primes[i] > 1) {
            var n = parseInt((Math.pow(parseInt(i), primes[i] + 1) - 1) / (parseInt(i) - 1))
            console.log(n);
            total *= n;
        } else {
            var n = parseInt(i) + 1
            console.log(n);
            total *= n;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1) return 1;
    return total;
}
```

If I call `GetPrimeFactors(12)` I get this object: `{ '2': 2, '3': 1 }` which represents `2^2+3`, the name is the base value and the value is the exponent. `SumOfDivisors` uses that object to do the math in the above linked article. The problem is that according to the Project Euler problem, 12 is the first abundant number. If I run 6 through `SumOfDivisors`, I get the proper prime factors (the object `{ '2': 1, '3': 1 }`) but it results in SumOfDivisors returning 12 making 6 look abundant. If you add up factors the inefficient way (bullet B in the math article) then you obviously get the factors 1, 2, and 3 which makes 6 a perfect number.

I remember in my old C# code that I used this same technique: finding primes and using them to sum divisors. But I didn't have this problem with 6 (and probably many more numbers). I'm at a lose for what I'm doing wrong here. What am I doing wrong when I'm finding the sum of divisors? Is this technique known not to work for certain values? Am I glazing over a special case? Am I snagged on a Javascript gotcha?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what the article says.

Project Euler actually asks for the sum of proper divisors:

28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28

While the article specifies the algorithm for the sum of positive integral divisors:

12 would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 = 28

Note that the first case doesn't include the number itself, while the second does. That is why 6 is not abundant (1 + 2 + 3 = 6), but the sum of its integral divisors is 12 (1 + 2 + 3 + 6).

Comment: So the simple answer is that I should subtract the number from the SumOfDivisors output?

Comment: Now to tackle why my answer is exactly 995 off of the actual answer... The problem is probably elsewhere though.